# How can I copy music files from multiple playlists, and keep the directory structure similar?

Tags: mount, files, music, playlists

So my source directory would be `~/Music`, and destination directory would be `/mnt/Music/`.  Say the file named "music1.mp3" is located under `~/Music/dir1/music1.mp3`.  I also got another file in a playlist named "music2.mp3" located in `~/Music/dir2/music2.mp3`.
How can I mirror the destination so that "music1.mp3" would copy to `/mnt/Music/dir1/` & "music2.mp3" under `/mnt/Music/dir2/`?

Comment: You will have to manually create them I think unless you use the mount option but here you don't need to copy as anything there will be auto-tranferred on mount!

Comment: I may not understand your issue, but isn't this just a matter of copying the contents of your Music folder to your /mnt/Music folder? Can be done with your file manager, but rsync would allow to maintain both folders very effectively in sync.

Comment: @vanadium I think you're right.  After looking more carefully at the man page, the `--files-from` flag might be the solution.

Comment: I still do not understand really what you want to achieve. A mere copy/paste already will do what you want, in as far as I understand yout problem. How are "playlists" involved in your problem? Clarify your question.

Comment: @vanadium I don't want to copy my entire music library.  I just want to copy files from multiple playlists, and retain all of the playlists I set up

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the terminal.

**Use the appropriate cp command**

1. Make sure your Music folder is your current working directory

`cd ~/Music/`

2. Perform a copy. Specify your source file as the path starting from your `~/Music` folder. Specifying `/mnt/Music` as the destination. The trick comes in using the option `--target`. This will recreate the relative path of the file into the target. The command thus will look like:

`cp --target dir1/music1.mp3 /mnt/Music`

Because of the --target option, the file `music1.mp3` will be copied to a folder `dir1` under your `/mnt/Music` folder. If the folder does not exist, it will be created.

**Automate for your entire playlist**

Because this is bash, it can be automated. You can directly use your playlist if it just lists the music files with their relative paths in plain text format. If your music player software uses a different format, you will need to export the playlist in text format, such as the m3u format, first. In following example, it is assumed that you have a playlist `myplaylist.m3u`that contains two music files:

```
dir1/music1.mp3
dir2/music2.mp3
```

Following line will cause all files in the playlist to be copied to the `/mnt/Music` folder under their respective folder. This will work also for large playlists. Again, your current working directory needs to be `~/Music` for this to work. Otherwise, the files under that folder will not be found.

```
cat myplaylist.m3u | while read f; do cp --target "$f" /mnt/Music; done
```

`"$f"` will be a line from your text file `myplaylist.m3u`.